# make a style for a class and remove it for others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

i want to make a css class for a `<text>` in `<svg>` and remove this class for all the `<text>` that have the same class, something like that:

```
  $('.svg-text').on('click', function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('rel'); 
       $(this).addClass("svg-style").siblings(".svg-text").removeClass("svg-style");
    });
```

THis is an exemple of `<text>` tag in `<svg>` :

```
<g id="Group-4" transform="translate(13.000000, 336.000000)">
    <text rel="text-2"  class="svg-text" id="Publication-des-résu" font-family="Roboto-Bold, Roboto" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#191919">
        <tspan x="25" y="11">PUBLICATION DES RÉSULTATS DE TEST</tspan>
    </text>
    <g id="Group-9-Copy-6">
        <circle id="Oval" stroke="#B5004F" stroke-width="1.5" cx="7.42857143" cy="7.42857143" r="7.42857143"></circle>
        <g id="info" transform="translate(5.714286, 3.428571)" fill="#B5004F" fill-rule="nonzero">
            <path d="M3.28882286,6.82532571 L3.18192,7.26233143 C2.86121143,7.38891429 2.60502857,7.48525714 2.41426286,7.55149714 C2.22329143,7.61794286 2.00139429,7.65099429 1.74857143,7.65099429 C1.36032,7.65099429 1.05833143,7.55588571 0.842948571,7.36697143 C0.627565714,7.17730286 0.51984,6.93696 0.51984,6.64539429 C0.51984,6.53252571 0.527657143,6.41643429 0.543908571,6.29814857 C0.560297143,6.17972571 0.586354286,6.04635429 0.622011429,5.89728 L1.02281143,4.47867429 C1.05846857,4.34283429 1.08877714,4.21412571 1.11305143,4.09241143 C1.13766857,3.97145143 1.14953143,3.86016 1.14953143,3.75997714 C1.14953143,3.57881143 1.11202286,3.45209143 1.03734857,3.38084571 C0.962674286,3.30980571 0.820182857,3.27373714 0.60864,3.27373714 C0.505028571,3.27373714 0.398537143,3.29033143 0.289988571,3.32242286 C0.18096,3.35465143 0.0877714286,3.38578286 0.00953142857,3.41472 L0.116708571,2.97737143 C0.379268571,2.87046857 0.63024,2.77892571 0.870308571,2.70294857 C1.11037714,2.62676571 1.33721143,2.58864 1.55177143,2.58864 C1.93734857,2.58864 2.23488,2.68182857 2.44381714,2.86820571 C2.65275429,3.05472 2.75718857,3.29650286 2.75718857,3.59444571 C2.75718857,3.65609143 2.75033143,3.76470857 2.73558857,3.91995429 C2.72118857,4.07554286 2.69437714,4.21810286 2.65529143,4.34777143 L2.25620571,5.76068571 C2.22349714,5.87417143 2.19408,6.00390857 2.16850286,6.14989714 C2.14210286,6.29492571 2.12948571,6.40573714 2.12948571,6.48006857 C2.12948571,6.66768 2.17131429,6.79577143 2.25517714,6.86386286 C2.33965714,6.93195429 2.48516571,6.96582857 2.69184,6.96582857 C2.78886857,6.96582857 2.89926857,6.94861714 3.02194286,6.91481143 C3.14427429,6.88100571 3.23348571,6.85131429 3.28882286,6.82532571 Z M3.39003429,0.893485714 C3.39003429,1.13965714 3.29725714,1.34989714 3.11081143,1.52276571 C2.92484571,1.69625143 2.70075429,1.78306286 2.43860571,1.78306286 C2.17563429,1.78306286 1.95099429,1.69625143 1.76290286,1.52276571 C1.57515429,1.34982857 1.48107429,1.13965714 1.48107429,0.893485714 C1.48107429,0.647794286 1.57515429,0.437211429 1.76290286,0.262148571 C1.95065143,0.08736 2.17570286,0 2.43860571,0 C2.70068571,0 2.92484571,0.0875657143 3.11081143,0.262148571 C3.29739429,0.437211429 3.39003429,0.647862857 3.39003429,0.893485714 Z" id="Shape"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Group-5" transform="translate(13.000000, 367.000000)">
    <text rel="text-3"  class="svg-text" id="Vérification-de-la-c" font-family="Roboto-Bold, Roboto" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#191919">
        <tspan x="25" y="11">VÉRIFICATION DE LA CONFORMITÉ</tspan>
    </text>
    <g id="Group-9-Copy-7">
        <circle id="Oval" stroke="#B5004F" stroke-width="1.5" cx="7.42857143" cy="7.42857143" r="7.42857143"></circle>
        <g id="info" transform="translate(5.714286, 3.428571)" fill="#B5004F" fill-rule="nonzero">
            <path d="M3.28882286,6.82532571 L3.18192,7.26233143 C2.86121143,7.38891429 2.60502857,7.48525714 2.41426286,7.55149714 C2.22329143,7.61794286 2.00139429,7.65099429 1.74857143,7.65099429 C1.36032,7.65099429 1.05833143,7.55588571 0.842948571,7.36697143 C0.627565714,7.17730286 0.51984,6.93696 0.51984,6.64539429 C0.51984,6.53252571 0.527657143,6.41643429 0.543908571,6.29814857 C0.560297143,6.17972571 0.586354286,6.04635429 0.622011429,5.89728 L1.02281143,4.47867429 C1.05846857,4.34283429 1.08877714,4.21412571 1.11305143,4.09241143 C1.13766857,3.97145143 1.14953143,3.86016 1.14953143,3.75997714 C1.14953143,3.57881143 1.11202286,3.45209143 1.03734857,3.38084571 C0.962674286,3.30980571 0.820182857,3.27373714 0.60864,3.27373714 C0.505028571,3.27373714 0.398537143,3.29033143 0.289988571,3.32242286 C0.18096,3.35465143 0.0877714286,3.38578286 0.00953142857,3.41472 L0.116708571,2.97737143 C0.379268571,2.87046857 0.63024,2.77892571 0.870308571,2.70294857 C1.11037714,2.62676571 1.33721143,2.58864 1.55177143,2.58864 C1.93734857,2.58864 2.23488,2.68182857 2.44381714,2.86820571 C2.65275429,3.05472 2.75718857,3.29650286 2.75718857,3.59444571 C2.75718857,3.65609143 2.75033143,3.76470857 2.73558857,3.91995429 C2.72118857,4.07554286 2.69437714,4.21810286 2.65529143,4.34777143 L2.25620571,5.76068571 C2.22349714,5.87417143 2.19408,6.00390857 2.16850286,6.14989714 C2.14210286,6.29492571 2.12948571,6.40573714 2.12948571,6.48006857 C2.12948571,6.66768 2.17131429,6.79577143 2.25517714,6.86386286 C2.33965714,6.93195429 2.48516571,6.96582857 2.69184,6.96582857 C2.78886857,6.96582857 2.89926857,6.94861714 3.02194286,6.91481143 C3.14427429,6.88100571 3.23348571,6.85131429 3.28882286,6.82532571 Z M3.39003429,0.893485714 C3.39003429,1.13965714 3.29725714,1.34989714 3.11081143,1.52276571 C2.92484571,1.69625143 2.70075429,1.78306286 2.43860571,1.78306286 C2.17563429,1.78306286 1.95099429,1.69625143 1.76290286,1.52276571 C1.57515429,1.34982857 1.48107429,1.13965714 1.48107429,0.893485714 C1.48107429,0.647794286 1.57515429,0.437211429 1.76290286,0.262148571 C1.95065143,0.08736 2.17570286,0 2.43860571,0 C2.70068571,0 2.92484571,0.0875657143 3.11081143,0.262148571 C3.29739429,0.437211429 3.39003429,0.647862857 3.39003429,0.893485714 Z" id="Shape"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Comment: I don't understand whats the problem or what is main goal.

Comment: Are you wanting to put the svg-style class on only the clicked <text> and make sure it is removed from any of the other <text>s that have the class svg-text?

Comment: @AHaworth  yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this as the onlclick function you will first clear all the svg-style s (if any) from the s that have class svg-text and then add svg-style to the clicked text.

```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("svg-text svg-style");
  if (elements){
    for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove("svg-style");
    }
  }
  this.classList.add("svg-style");
```

Comment: If you just simply converted my answer into vanilla JS, you should also add how to call that function on click using vanilla JS. With your answer OP is just combining the two un- necessary... @MeryemAchemlal

Comment: @ikiK I hadn't seen your answer when I was answering - I spent some time testing. I'll look at your answer to see if it is doing something extra. It seemed clear to me to say just use the code I provided as the onclick function - sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.svg-text').on('click', function() {
  //on every click
  var id = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("text.svg-text").removeClass("svg-style");
  // first remove class from every text with class .svg-text
  $(this).addClass("svg-style");
  // then re-apply on only clicked one
});
```

```css
.svg-text {
  background-color: red
}

.svg-style {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<g id="Group-4" transform="translate(13.000000, 336.000000)">
  <text rel="text-2" class="svg-text" id="Publication-des-résu" font-family="Roboto-Bold, Roboto" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#191919">
        <tspan x="25" y="11">PUBLICATION DES RÉSULTATS DE TEST</tspan>
    </text>
  <g id="Group-9-Copy-6">
    <circle id="Oval" stroke="#B5004F" stroke-width="1.5" cx="7.42857143" cy="7.42857143" r="7.42857143"></circle>
    <g id="info" transform="translate(5.714286, 3.428571)" fill="#B5004F" fill-rule="nonzero">
      <path d="M3.28882286,6.82532571 L3.18192,7.26233143 C2.86121143,7.38891429 2.60502857,7.48525714 2.41426286,7.55149714 C2.22329143,7.61794286 2.00139429,7.65099429 1.74857143,7.65099429 C1.36032,7.65099429 1.05833143,7.55588571 0.842948571,7.36697143 C0.627565714,7.17730286 0.51984,6.93696 0.51984,6.64539429 C0.51984,6.53252571 0.527657143,6.41643429 0.543908571,6.29814857 C0.560297143,6.17972571 0.586354286,6.04635429 0.622011429,5.89728 L1.02281143,4.47867429 C1.05846857,4.34283429 1.08877714,4.21412571 1.11305143,4.09241143 C1.13766857,3.97145143 1.14953143,3.86016 1.14953143,3.75997714 C1.14953143,3.57881143 1.11202286,3.45209143 1.03734857,3.38084571 C0.962674286,3.30980571 0.820182857,3.27373714 0.60864,3.27373714 C0.505028571,3.27373714 0.398537143,3.29033143 0.289988571,3.32242286 C0.18096,3.35465143 0.0877714286,3.38578286 0.00953142857,3.41472 L0.116708571,2.97737143 C0.379268571,2.87046857 0.63024,2.77892571 0.870308571,2.70294857 C1.11037714,2.62676571 1.33721143,2.58864 1.55177143,2.58864 C1.93734857,2.58864 2.23488,2.68182857 2.44381714,2.86820571 C2.65275429,3.05472 2.75718857,3.29650286 2.75718857,3.59444571 C2.75718857,3.65609143 2.75033143,3.76470857 2.73558857,3.91995429 C2.72118857,4.07554286 2.69437714,4.21810286 2.65529143,4.34777143 L2.25620571,5.76068571 C2.22349714,5.87417143 2.19408,6.00390857 2.16850286,6.14989714 C2.14210286,6.29492571 2.12948571,6.40573714 2.12948571,6.48006857 C2.12948571,6.66768 2.17131429,6.79577143 2.25517714,6.86386286 C2.33965714,6.93195429 2.48516571,6.96582857 2.69184,6.96582857 C2.78886857,6.96582857 2.89926857,6.94861714 3.02194286,6.91481143 C3.14427429,6.88100571 3.23348571,6.85131429 3.28882286,6.82532571 Z M3.39003429,0.893485714 C3.39003429,1.13965714 3.29725714,1.34989714 3.11081143,1.52276571 C2.92484571,1.69625143 2.70075429,1.78306286 2.43860571,1.78306286 C2.17563429,1.78306286 1.95099429,1.69625143 1.76290286,1.52276571 C1.57515429,1.34982857 1.48107429,1.13965714 1.48107429,0.893485714 C1.48107429,0.647794286 1.57515429,0.437211429 1.76290286,0.262148571 C1.95065143,0.08736 2.17570286,0 2.43860571,0 C2.70068571,0 2.92484571,0.0875657143 3.11081143,0.262148571 C3.29739429,0.437211429 3.39003429,0.647862857 3.39003429,0.893485714 Z"
        id="Shape"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
<g id="Group-5" transform="translate(13.000000, 367.000000)">
  <text rel="text-3" class="svg-text" id="Vérification-de-la-c" font-family="Roboto-Bold, Roboto" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#191919">
        <tspan x="25" y="11">VÉRIFICATION DE LA CONFORMITÉ</tspan>
    </text>
  <g id="Group-9-Copy-7">
    <circle id="Oval" stroke="#B5004F" stroke-width="1.5" cx="7.42857143" cy="7.42857143" r="7.42857143"></circle>
    <g id="info" transform="translate(5.714286, 3.428571)" fill="#B5004F" fill-rule="nonzero">
      <path d="M3.28882286,6.82532571 L3.18192,7.26233143 C2.86121143,7.38891429 2.60502857,7.48525714 2.41426286,7.55149714 C2.22329143,7.61794286 2.00139429,7.65099429 1.74857143,7.65099429 C1.36032,7.65099429 1.05833143,7.55588571 0.842948571,7.36697143 C0.627565714,7.17730286 0.51984,6.93696 0.51984,6.64539429 C0.51984,6.53252571 0.527657143,6.41643429 0.543908571,6.29814857 C0.560297143,6.17972571 0.586354286,6.04635429 0.622011429,5.89728 L1.02281143,4.47867429 C1.05846857,4.34283429 1.08877714,4.21412571 1.11305143,4.09241143 C1.13766857,3.97145143 1.14953143,3.86016 1.14953143,3.75997714 C1.14953143,3.57881143 1.11202286,3.45209143 1.03734857,3.38084571 C0.962674286,3.30980571 0.820182857,3.27373714 0.60864,3.27373714 C0.505028571,3.27373714 0.398537143,3.29033143 0.289988571,3.32242286 C0.18096,3.35465143 0.0877714286,3.38578286 0.00953142857,3.41472 L0.116708571,2.97737143 C0.379268571,2.87046857 0.63024,2.77892571 0.870308571,2.70294857 C1.11037714,2.62676571 1.33721143,2.58864 1.55177143,2.58864 C1.93734857,2.58864 2.23488,2.68182857 2.44381714,2.86820571 C2.65275429,3.05472 2.75718857,3.29650286 2.75718857,3.59444571 C2.75718857,3.65609143 2.75033143,3.76470857 2.73558857,3.91995429 C2.72118857,4.07554286 2.69437714,4.21810286 2.65529143,4.34777143 L2.25620571,5.76068571 C2.22349714,5.87417143 2.19408,6.00390857 2.16850286,6.14989714 C2.14210286,6.29492571 2.12948571,6.40573714 2.12948571,6.48006857 C2.12948571,6.66768 2.17131429,6.79577143 2.25517714,6.86386286 C2.33965714,6.93195429 2.48516571,6.96582857 2.69184,6.96582857 C2.78886857,6.96582857 2.89926857,6.94861714 3.02194286,6.91481143 C3.14427429,6.88100571 3.23348571,6.85131429 3.28882286,6.82532571 Z M3.39003429,0.893485714 C3.39003429,1.13965714 3.29725714,1.34989714 3.11081143,1.52276571 C2.92484571,1.69625143 2.70075429,1.78306286 2.43860571,1.78306286 C2.17563429,1.78306286 1.95099429,1.69625143 1.76290286,1.52276571 C1.57515429,1.34982857 1.48107429,1.13965714 1.48107429,0.893485714 C1.48107429,0.647794286 1.57515429,0.437211429 1.76290286,0.262148571 C1.95065143,0.08736 2.17570286,0 2.43860571,0 C2.70068571,0 2.92484571,0.0875657143 3.11081143,0.262148571 C3.29739429,0.437211429 3.39003429,0.647862857 3.39003429,0.893485714 Z"
        id="Shape"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```